# Chrome menu (3 dots) is missing. How do I get it back?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Windows 10 with Chrome latest version. The menu (3 dots) is missing. Does anyone know how to get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Try the right-most icon on the menu bar.  Chrome sometimes changes it to let you know something needs your attention.  (E.g., to restart Chrome for an update.)

Or you can use Alt-F to open the menu from the keyboard.

Comment: I have also seen malicious extensions replace the icon. Remove the extension.

Comment: Thanks, it was an AdBlocker. FYI: Alt/F7 didn't work but the rightmost icon (an ! point icon) did bring up settings and then I could remove the AdBlocker.